# C - yes/no prompt executes more than once

Tags: c, prompt

I'm working on a portion of a program that deals with overwriting files in a directory. Overwriting the files is easy... but apparently making the prompt that asks users if they wish to overwrite the file is not. For example: if I wish to overwrite two files (fileOne.txt, fileTwo.txt), I need to prompt the user twice (once for each file). With my current prompt, if I prompt the user to overwrite fileOne.txt, both fileOne.txt and fileTwo.txt will be overwritten. If there are more than two files to overwrite, it will overwrite only two consecutive files. I believe it has something to do with hitting "Enter", but I just have no clue...

```
if(((int)getHeader.deleted - 48) == 0) {
        if(access(getHeader.file_name, F_OK) != -1) { /* File exists in directory, check for overwrite */
            printf("%s already exists. Would you like to overwrite it? (y/n)\n", getHeader.file_name);
            scanf("%c", buffer);
            while(!validResponse) {
                if(buffer[0] == 'y' || buffer[0] == 'Y') {
                    validResponse = 1;
                    printf("DO SOMETHING - Files will be overwritten\n");
                } else if(buffer[0] == 'n' || buffer[0] == 'N') {
                    validResponse = 1;
                    printf("DO SOMETHING - File will be skipped\n");
                } else {
                    printf("Invalid response... Would you like to overwrite %s? (y/n)\n", getHeader.file_name);
                    scanf("%c", buffer);
                } /* End if else */
            } /* End while */
        } /* End if */
    } /* End if */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read a single char you leave a newline in `stdin` you need to consume that:

```
scanf("%c", buffer);
getchar();  // consume the leftover '\n'
```

would do it, or in just oneline:

```
scanf(" %c", buffer); // the space will tell it to skip any "white space" characters
```

With just the code snippet you have here, if there was an invalid character entered at the first prompt, it would seem to skip by the `else`'s scanf (in reality it's reading the first leftover `'\n'`) and it will loop around again to get input.

Without seeing the rest of the code, presumably you have this all in a loop and that's why it's skipping over files in 2s. (`'Y'`, then `'\n'`)

Comment: Alternately, you could put a blank space in the format string: `scanf(" %c", buffer);` - this will tell `scanf` to skip leading whitespace and read the next *non*-whitespace character.

Comment: getchar(); did the trick. Thanks for the help

Comment: @JohnBode - Yup, lots of possibilities, I added yours as well.